# orthogonal basis for the complement

Tags: inner-products

Consider $\mathbb R^3$ with the standard inner product. Let $W$ be the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ spanned by $(1,0, -1)$.
Which of the following is a basis for the orthogonal complement of $W$?

1. $\{ ( 1, 0, 1), ( 0, 1, 0)\}$
2. $\{(1,2,1),(0,1,1)\}$
3. $\{(2,1,2),(4,2,4)\}$
4. $\{(2,-1,2),(1,3,1),(-1,-1,-1)\}$

only first set is orthogonal, so it should be correct option. but what is the correct method to solve this problem.

Comment: LaTeX + FAQ section = writing properly mathematics in this site

Comment: The basis for the orthogonal complement does not need to consist of orthogonal vectors. Hence your reasoning that for the first set is invalid. E.g. a basis for the orthogonal complement of the singleton $(0,0,0)$ could be $(1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)$.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that everybody would understand that [R!.3 means $\mathbb R^3$??

Comment: Actually i have copied from pdf formet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\dim W=1$, you know $\dim W^\perp = 3-1=2$, so $4$ is wrong.
The vectors must be linearly independant, so $3$ is wrong. Each of the vectors must be orthogonal to each element of $W$ (it suffices to check against a basis of $W$, here only against $(1,0,-1)$), so $2$ is wrong and $1$ is correct (it does not matter if the two vectors in $1$ are othogonal to *each other*).