# $M$ be the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ spanned by $(1,0,-1).$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Consider $\Bbb R^3$ with the standard inner product. Let $M$ be the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ spanned by $(1,0,-1).$ Which of the following is a basis for the orthogonal complement of $M\,\,?$
>
> 1. $\{(2,1,2),(4,2,4)\}$
> 2. $\{(2,-1,2),(1,3,1),(-1,-1,-1)\}$
> 3. $\{(1,0,1),(0,1,0)\}$
> 4. $\{(1,2,1),(0,1,1)\}$

Can someone explain it?

Comment: very similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/429757/8581)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the complement has dimension 2. You also know that each vector in the complement is orthogonal to $(1,0,-1)$, so the basis vectors are too. In other words, you need to check

a) Which set of vectors are linearly independent and span a two dimensional subspace.

b) Which set consists of vectors orthogonal to $(1,0,-1)$.

Comment: then option 3 is the winner.Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.